# How to output my code in one messagedialog using for loops

Tags: java, oop

I'm new to OOP and I'm creating a simple GUI program wherein I enter a number input and create a triangle starting from 0. I've got the logic to making the triangle, but when I output it, it shows one message dialog at a time. I have done this without the GUI, and now I'm trying to see how the code would look with GUI. I've included a sample of the output I want at the bottom of the code (That should be inside one message dialog).

```
     for(int i = 0; i <= number; ++i) {         // incrementation       
        for(int j = 0; j <= i; ++j) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, j + " ");    
        }

    }


    for(int i = number - 1; i >= 0; --i) {     //decrementation
        for(int j = 0; j <= i; ++j) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, j + " "); 
        }

    }
    //*
    //**
    //***
    //**
    //*
```

Comment: This will show message dialog on every iteration. What do you want t do?

Comment: System.out is applcation console - you wont see that anywhere in GUI.

Comment: Your use of `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()` will pause and wait for the user to acknowledge it, since it's inside the loop. That's exactly what you're asking it to do.

Comment: Basically, I want it to look like a triangle, rotated 90 degrees.

Comment: Perhaps you want to assemble a string using a `StringBuilder` and then output that at the end (outside of the loops.)

Comment: I havent been exposed to StringBuilder, but im willing to check it out. Could you refer me to a program similar to mine that is using StringBuilder?

Comment: Just check the API. Ist in JDK basics.

Answer (score 0):

putting aside if those loops works, you want do do something like that

```
StringBuilder b=new StringBuilder();

 for(int i = 0; i <= number; ++i) {         // incrementation       
    for(int j = 0; j <= i; ++j) {
    b.add(j + " ");    
    }

}


for(int i = number - 1; i >= 0; --i) {     //decrementation
    for(int j = 0; j <= i; ++j) {
       b.add(j + " ");    
    }

}


JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, b.toString());
```